# How to get wall videos using facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

user home page in facebook have a shared links from friends and pages, this links sometimes have youtube links I need to get these links, I tried to read

https://graph.facebook.com/userID/**home**?access_token=access_token

or

https://graph.facebook.com/userID/**feed**?access_token=access_token

and when I use

https://graph.facebook.com/userID/**links**?access_token=access_token

I only got links I shared it, not my friends or pages, while I need my friends and pages videos

my access token have a lot of permissions like: friends_status friends_videos photo_upload read_stream share_item status_update user_status user_videos video_upload

but still i cant get shared videos

what I have to do?

Comment: Are there any special privacy settings on those posts? Remember that a user can limit what data an application can access no matter what access token is used...

Comment: if i can see it throw my home page so the publisher set the privacy to friends only or public, and in this two cases i supposed to read them by the api calls

Comment: Nope - privacy when you are viewing the site as a user is slightly different from API privacy...

Comment: @YousefAbuSamak did you get this done?

Answer (score 1):

if you need the friends videos and above of your quires are not working, then this query you can give a try

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=friends.fields(videos.fields(source,embed_html))
```

this will return the user's all friends with their videos. Hope it helps if I got your question right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FQL` to get the list of all videos as explained in [this post](http://pulkitgoyal.in/2012/12/26/getting-all-photos-and-videos-from-facebook-news-feed/).

```
SELECT actor_id, created_time, likes, post_id, attachment 
FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key IN ( 
    SELECT filter_key 
    FROM stream_filter 
    WHERE uid = me() AND (name = "Video")
)
```

`stream_filter` contains the filters for filtering the stream of posts. This contains several filters that include the lists that the user has built and some default filters like the ones for photos and videos.

Comment: `FQL` is no longer supported.

Comment: August 8, 2016, FQL will no longer be available, reference:-https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/